# divi page make popup before img

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have problem with popup in my divi page.

I created popup then implemented same in my home page but my popup disappear then i scroll down for example:
[image]

Like you see my popup are after img. And  this is not looking good right, i wanna fix it.

[image]

my code:

```js
function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {

  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 23px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 280px;
}

/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
.form-container input[type=text], .form-container input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* When the inputs get focus, do something */
.form-container input[type=text]:focus, .form-container input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Set a style for the submit/login button */
.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}


.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: #f2835a;
}


.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



<div class="open-button" 

<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
    <h1>Patalpų dezinfekcija beta</h1>

    <h4>Patalpų dezinfekcija beta - 70ct/kv.m </h4>
  
    <h4>tel. <a href="tel:+5444565">+54645654656</a> <br>
    el. p. <a href="mailto:i546456o@456456456.com">45646@45645654.com</a> </h4>

   


    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Uždaryti</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I cant found solution on my own. Please any info how to solve this issue will be very nice.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible with the code you provided, could you try to reproduce it in a snippet (Ctr-m when in edit question mode) and post the snippet?

Comment: i do what. possible fixed tab make more up? idk then where is my problem. Because i use wordpress divi for build my page. And its a bit hard task, to insert this code.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually i dont understand what you are trying to say. So please use
> below CSS and HTML for your reference. There you can edit the modal as
> per your requirement.

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*** Html part ***/
<body>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: your code dont work. Im using wordpress, divi for build my website design, My code work, but form are after imgs, i wanna make before, because its not look good.

Comment: @Kalakutas Actually i dont understand what you are expecting. I thought you have problem with popup. Thats why i have given you as reference not the exact one. Show me your output what you are expecting If you are facing any overlapping issue in css.